# How to enable discrete GPU in Lubuntu 21.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lubuntu, amd-graphics

I have DELL Inspiron 5520 laptop with Lubuntu 21.04 installed and working properly. This laptop has a normal GPU (Intel) and a discrete GPU (Radeon 7600m). When I ran the upgrade I noticed that Lubuntu recognized the discrete GPU and installed its drivers correctly. But the question is, how can I enable that discrete GPU (Radeon) for using specific apps and games in Lubuntu 21.04?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
DRI_PRIME=1 app_you_want_to_run_into_discrete
```

you can also add "DRI..." indicator inside the destination run box desktop icon too.

Edit: you can check this option works reading temperatures with **[lm-sensors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lm_sensors)**

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```